# How to make flex control visible while loading map activity from the native extension for android?

Tags: android, android-layout, flex-mobile, air-native-extension

I am stuck at the point where i want to show flex control like buttons and labels etc. at the bottom and a native android Map on the Top. What happens is the map activity covers the whole screen. Is there any way to setFrame of the Map view as there is in IOS. Or is there another way so that i can show flex control as well as a native android map in a single view.

Answer (score 0):

You should create layout for location map using xml.Place mapview at the top and buttons at the bottom in this xml.

Comment: thanks for the reply but my controls will be on Flex app not in android app.only the native android map will be of android.

Comment: Hi, what native extension are u using for the map? is one u created?